# Build ionic windows 10 app in VS 2015: Exception Module 'ngLocale' is not available

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, windows-10-universal, windows-8.1-universal

I tried to build my ionic app with VS 2015 in order to deploy it on windows 10 devices. I got the project setup and everything ist basically working fine but on app start i always get the following exception.

> Exception was thrown at line 10594, column 11 in
>   ms-appx-web://****/ionic.bundle.js
>   0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'ngLocale' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or
>   forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
>   dependencies as the second argument.

I checked the app for modules which are not included but found nothing. Its wierd because on android/ios no error is thrown. I also downloaded the blank ionic template and i get the same error. I already read through stackoverflow and google but found only unanswered/outdated posts. Did anyone solved this problem?

thanks for your help
Peter

Comment: I made a demo and didn't reproduce your problem. I used [this template](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4e44ba8b-a4c8-4106-b70e-00d63241a54a?SRC=VSIDE).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used the same template without any changes and always get this error. Dont know what to do...

Comment: Are you still seeing this error? If you can post an example project with the error I can take a look and see what may be going on.